# Xamarin Forms DataTrigger causes NullReferenceException

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, datatrigger

I am attempting to use a simple `DataTrigger` element within the XAML of a Xamarin Forms page:

```xml
<Frame BackgroundColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Frame.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Frame" Binding="{Binding IsValid}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{x:Static Color.Lime}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Frame.Triggers>
</Frame>
```

This configuration crashes the application with what is effectively a `NullReferenceException`:

> Java.Lang.NullPointerExceptionAttempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.isMutable()' on a null object reference

If I comment out the `Setter` in the above sample, the application runs normally but, of course, the trigger doesn't work.

Can anyone please suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can't reproduce it. Wich versions (Xamarin.Forms, Android) are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it!

I had a look at the decompiled version. This is a bug that occurs when the frame has a height of 0.

[image]

And this causes the error in `FrameOnPropertyChanged`

[image]

Adding `Padding="1"` or `HeightRequest="1" WidthRequest="1"` to your Frame should fix it, except there is something forcing it to 0.